# Set default languages for Google Translate

Tags: google-translate

How can I set the gadget so that it will default as English to Spanish or Spanish to English which is what I use most?  Every time I reopen the page, it defaults to English to German and I have to change it **every single time**.

Answer (score 4):

you can force it at URL level like this:

- **SPA > ENG https://translate.google.com/?hl=en#es/en/**
- **ENG > SPA https://translate.google.com/?hl=en#en/es/**

(I have it saved as a bookmark so I can load it with just one single click)

Answer (score 2):

The selection is saved in a cookie. When you allow cookies it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox I go to Preferences under Menu/Add ons/Extensions and there are default From/To languages. Set these to auto/en or auto/es. I don't think you can give it a default target when translating from your default language.

I had the problem that it decided that my default target language was Spanish which I rarely read and don't understand. This did solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Manually add 'Spanish to English' cookie to Chrome & bookmark it.

Search Google Translate > 
Set languages to Spanish to English > 
Copy the URL > Go to Chrome settings > 
Search Cookies > Site settings > Cookies and site data > 
Click Add next to Allow > Paste the URL

Then add a bookmark to the translated page.